# Compile error when trying to run make

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

I have the following error when trying to run `make` command,

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../libcppunit.a when searching for -lcppunit
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libcppunit.a when searching for -lcppunit
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcppunit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cppunit] Error 1
```

I have installed `libcppunit-dev` but the problem persists.

I have looked for solutions but no results.

Any idea how to solve it?

1) I am using Ubuntu 12.10 64bits

2) I am running `gcc 4.7.2`

3) I am trying to compile a program made for a research group. I am sure that it is properly built.

Comment: What's the output of `ls /usr/lib | grep lcppunit`?

Comment: None, returns nothing... :/ However sudo apt-get install libcppunit-dev output is: libcppunit-dev is already the newest version.

Comment: have you tried reinstalling `libcppunit` ? Try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libcppunit-dev`

Comment: Yes, I just re-install libcppunit, but the problem persists.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us 1) What version of Ubuntu you are using and whether it is 32 or 64bit; 2) What version of `gcc` you are running and 3) What you are trying to compile.

Comment: If you are using something higher than Precise, `libcppunit-dev` installs the static library to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a`, which leads me to think that you shouldn't have a file at `/usr/lib/libcppunit.a`.

Comment: Actually I have a file at /usr/lib/libcppunit.a but I do not have anything at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcppunit.a (the closest thing is libcppunit_subunit.a)

Comment: Please move your solution into an answer. Thanks. You can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solution found by OP on question:*

> Problem solved. The problem was that the Makefile was ready to compile
>   in a 32 bits machines but my computer is 64 bits. So removing "-m32"
>   in Makefile was enough.